# generating the 20 normal directions of an icosahedron without the vertices?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms

I want to know if there is a mechanism I can use to enumerate all 20 normal directions of an icosahedron without making the vertices.

i.e. a formula/algorithm that I can use to print out 20 unit vectors such that each corresponds to a face in the icosahedron.

Comment: Take the dual of the icosahedron and use those vertices.

Comment: I don't have the icosahedron to begin with. I am trying to generate it.

Comment: Just create one! Use a dodecahedron.

Answer (score 3):

The dodecahedron is the [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_polyhedron) of the icosahedron: if you swap the roles of vertices and faces, you turn one into the other. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates has coordinates for the 20 dodecahedron vertices. They have length $\sqrt3$ so you might want to divide by that to get unit length.